# SQl server search, using FREETEXTTABLE (Transact-SQL)

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, freetexttable

Thanks in Advance.

I am implementing FREETEXTTABLE into a search form. I wanted to know how the following queries would behave and what results would be returned. Also, would like to know if brackets form a valid part of a query.

So, if I search for "Abuse AND (procedure OR legislation)", would this be a valid search query for FREETEXTTABLE? Or would I need to pass in "Abuse AND procedure OR legislation".

My worry is that if I pass in "Abuse AND procedure OR legislation", it will find results that are "Abuse AND Procedure" Or "Legislation" when I want the results that have "Abuse" AND "Procedure OR Legislation".

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FREETEXTABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177652.aspx) does not interpret the word "AND" as a keyword, like for example when using CONTAINS. Instead it will be considered as a noise word.

FREETEXTABLE uses character-based data types for values that match the meaning, but not the exact wording.

You may insetead wish to look at the use of [CONTAINSTABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx) as this does allow the use of the keywords AND / OR.

Comment: So we could do a standard CONTAINSTABLE to search for: "Abuse AND (procedure OR legislation)". And that would give me the desired results?